# Replace percent-escaped characters in string (%20, %5B, …) with bash

Tags: string, bash, utf-8, ascii

I have strings containing percent-escaped characters like `%20` and `%5B`, and I would like to transform it to "normal" characters like `\` for `%20` and `[` for `%5B`.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The builtin printf in bash has a special format specifier (i.e. %b) which converts \x** to the corresponding  value:

```
$ str='foo%20%5B12%5D'
$ printf "%b\n" "${str//%/\\x}"
foo [12]
```

Comment: I have done some minor corrections and written a condensed version here: http://pastebin.com/y8KBgVA2

Comment: Thanks a lot, the short version is hard to maintain for me, so I keep the long one.

Comment: Using `echo` this can be made a tiny bit shorter: `echo -e "${str//%/\x}"`. Using either `printf` or `echo` the `\\x` need not to be escaped twice: `\x`.

Comment: Very nice and thanks for your good explanation @marco

Answer (score 2):

Finally, thanks to #bash IRC channel, I found a "not so bad" solution :

```
echo `echo string%20with%5Bsome%23 | sed 's/%/\\\x/g'`
```

Comment: I don't see what the surrounding `echo` buys you. Does `echo string%20with%5Bsome%23 | sed 's/%/\\\x/g'` not work?

Comment: @Thanatos: The sed merely changes `string%20with%5Bsome%23` into `string\x20with\x5Bsome\x23`. Passing this to `echo -e` will mean that the `\x..` escapes are correctly processed. [Missing `-e` and the backticks should be wrapped in double quotes: `echo -e "$(echo string%20with%5Bsome%23 | sed 's/%/\\\x/g')"`.]

Comment: if you want to change from a file: `echo \`sed 's/%/\\\x/g' $file\` > $newfile`