# What does %5B and %5D in POST requests stand for?

Tags: java, post, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to write a Java class to log in to a certain website. The data sent in the POST request to log in is

`user%5Blogin%5D=username&user%5Bpassword%5D=123456`

I'm curious what the `%5B` and `%5D` means in the key **user login**.

How do I decode these data?

Answer (score 677, accepted):

As per this answer over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5082400/1108032): `str='foo%20%5B12%5D'` encodes `foo [12]`:

```
%20 is space
%22 is quotes
%5B is '['
and %5D is ']'
```

This is called [percent encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) and is used in encoding special characters in the url parameter values.

**EDIT** By the way as I was reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI#Description, it just occurred to me why so many people make the same search. See the note on the bottom of the page:

> Also note that if one wishes to follow the more recent [RFC3986](http://tools.ietf.org/pdf/rfc3986.pdf)
> for URL's, making square brackets reserved (for IPv6) and thus not
> encoded when forming something which could be part of a URL (such as a
> host), the following may help.

```
function fixedEncodeURI (str) {
    return encodeURI(str).replace(/%5B/g, '[').replace(/%5D/g, ']');
}
```

Hopefully this will help people sort out their problems when they stumble upon this question.

Comment: sent you an email at qualifast.bg. can you please check

Comment: @zatef a colleague of mine has answered you yesterday, please check if  his email went in the spam folder

Answer (score 53):

They represent `[` and `]`. The encoding is called ["URL encoding"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Answer (score 20):

`[]` is replaced by `%5B%5D` at URL encoding time.

Answer (score 12):

Well it's the usual [url encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url_encoding)

So they stand for `[`, respectively `]`

Answer (score 10):

To find out these values you can simply use Console in your browser and do the following

```js
console.log(decodeURI('user%5Blogin%5D=username&user%5Bpassword%5D=123456'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Not least important is why these symbols occur in url.
See https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php#76792, specifically:

```
parse_str('foo[]=1&foo[]=2&foo[]=3', $bar);
```

the above produces:

```
$bar = ['foo' => ['1', '2', '3'] ];
```

and what is THE method to separate query vars in arrays (in php, at least).

Answer (score 1):

The data would probably have been posted originally from a web form looking a bit like this (but probably much more complicated):

```
<form action="http://example.com" method="post">

  User login    <input name="user[login]"    /><br />
  User password <input name="user[password]" /><br />

  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

If the method were "get" instead of "post", clicking the submit button would take you to a URL looking a bit like this:

> http://example.com/?user%5Blogin%5D=username&user%5Bpassword%5D=123456

or:

> http://example.com/?user[login]=username&user[password]=123456

The web server on the other end will likely take the `user[login]` and `user[password]` parameters, and make them into a `user` object with `login` and `password` fields containing those values.