# How I get only value ignoring the key

Tags: java, json

I have a json array in database. I want to get only value ignoring the key and send it to ajax call.

Json string I have while saving:

```
{
    "cells": 
    [
        {
            "type": "devs.TooledModel",
            "position": 
            {
                "x": 200,
                "y": 100
            },
            "size": 
            {
                "width": 71,
                "height": 100
            },
                ".": 
            {
                    "magnet": false
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to return the exact json array from database but I am getting a key appended because I am using a map in java servlet to retrieve json:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();

    while (rSet.next()) {
        Map<String, Object> row = new HashMap<>();
        row.put("JSON_Diagram", rSet.getString("JSON_INFO"));
        result.add(row);
    }
```

json received: `JSON_Diagram: "cells%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=devs.TooledModel&cells..`

How do I remove the key `JSON_Diagram` and get only value ? Tried with `Object value = result.get(0);` but didn't work

Comment: Do you only have to remove the `JSON_Diagram` or the complete set of keys?

Comment: only the word JSON_Diagram

Comment: I want to retrieve the exact json array without any changes

Comment: result.get(0).get("JSON_Diagram")

Comment: @TeenaGeorge Is this how json looks like when retrieved from db: `"cells%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=devs.TooledModel&cells` Special characters like percent are getting added

Comment: please try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966053/what-does-5b-and-5d-in-post-requests-stand-for

Comment: @TeenaGeorge Thanks TeenaGeorge the link helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So once you have the map just do a a `map.values`.

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#values()][1]

Then just use the resultant collection!

Comment: `List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();` Here is how I have the map

Answer (score 3):

You need to get a list of all the keys, loop over them and add them to your map and if you need only value add values only to list as shown in the example below:

```
Map<String,Object> row  = new HashMap<String,Object>();
    Iterator iter = rSet.keys();
    while(iter.hasNext()){
        String key = (String)iter.next();
        String value = rSet.getString(key);
        row.put(key,value);
        result.add(value);

    }
```

Comment: Is this how json looks like when retrieved from db: "cells%5B0%5D%5Btype%5D=devs.TooledModel&cells Special characters like percent are getting added. Is this normal