# GSP g:submitToRemote call injecting unwanted encoded square brackets around ID

Tags: ajax, grails, gsp

I cannot get my Groovy-Grails GSP to pass an ID in an AJAX g:submitToRemote call without injecting unwanted encoded square brackets around the ID.

I have a top level domain class, Top, that contains a Map of Section classes, called sections, and each Section contains a SubSection.

I need to pass the ID of the SubSection back to the server in the g:submitToRemote call.

I can display the SubSection ID on the GSP with the following, where 'sectionA' is the actual String key for the Map:

```
${topInsatance.sections.sectionA.subSection.id}
```

So in my example, the ID is 122.

```
<g:submitToRemote url="[action:'update', id: topInsatance.sections.sectionA.subSection.id ]" value="Update">
```

resulting in the bad POST:

```
.../update%5B122%5D
```

Just as an experiment, I tried passing just the topInstance.id, which was 116 in my example:

```
<g:submitToRemote url="[action:'update', id: topInsatance.id ]" value="Update">
```

resulting in the good POST:

```
.../update/116
```

Which has the correct format, but wrong ID. I need the subSection ID.

I also tried:

```
<g:set var="subSection" value= "${topInsatance.sections.sectionA.subSection}" />
```

and then:

```
<g:submitToRemote url="[action:'update', id: subSection.id ]" value="Update">
```

resulting in the bad POST:

```
.../update%5B122%5D
```

I also tried:

```
<g:set var="subSectionId" value= "${topInsatance.sections.sectionA.subSection.id}" />
```

and then:

```
<g:submitToRemote url="[action:'update', id: subSectionId ]" value="Update">
```

resulting in the bad POST:

```
.../update%5B122%5D
```

So it is always putting the encoded brackets around the subSectionId, no matter what I try.

Why does

```
topInsatance.id
```

work, but

```
subSection.id
subSectionId
```

not work?

Reference: [What does %5B and %5D in POST requests stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966053/what-does-5b-and-5d-in-post-requests-stand-for)

Edit: Adding more info about domain classes. The top level domain class is:

```
class Top {
  Map sections
  static hasMany = [ sections: Section ]
  ...
}

class Section {
  SubSection subSection  // only one
  static belongsTo = [ top: Top ]
  ...
}

class SubSection {
  // some content
}
```

When the applications runs, a section with the key "sectionA" is added to the Top instance sections Map.

Comment: Is `sections` a collection on your domain class? If so then the brackets are there because of that.

Comment: Yes, sections is a collection (Map), but I am referencing a specific one, 'sectionA', and getting its subSection ID. (There is only one subSection in each section.) How can I prevent the brackets from getting inserted?

Comment: Probably not related to the problem but why do you have quotes around `sectionA` in `topInsatance.sections.'sectionA'.subSection.id`?

Comment: Thanks Jeff, you are correct, the quotes around 'sectionA' were not needed, but unfortunately removing them did not solve my bracket problem.

Comment: Assuming `sectionA` is a property of an element inside the collection? You might want to post your full Domain classes so we all get a better idea of what you are doing.

Comment: "sectionA" is the key value (String) into the Top.sections Map.  There are several sections, "sectionA", "sectionB", etc.. The g:submitToRemote should return the ID of the SubSection within a given section, in this case its called "sectionA". I've added more info about the Domain classes.

Comment: Out of curiosity what happens when you use `topInstance.sections['sectionA'].subSection.id`?

Comment: Thank you Joshua Moore! That was it! .sections.sectionA.subSection.id always caused the brackets to be injected, but .sections['sectionA'].subSection.id worked as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would seem since you are using a `Map` you need to make sure Groovy understands you don't expect a collection of values back. So, use the following:

`topInstance.sections['sectionA'].subSection.id`