# Serialize form but checkbox array convert to comma separated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form:

```
<form id="filter_form">
   <select name="type">
      <option value="second">second</option>
   </select>
   <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="new_york" />
   <input type="checkbox" name="city[]" value="washington" />
</form>
```

and this event in js:

```
    $('#filter_form').on('change', function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "properties",
            method: 'GET',
            data: $("#filter_form").serialize(),
            success: function(result){
            }
        });
    });
```

In this moment the url is built like this:

```
properties?transaction_type=second&city%5B%5D=new_york&city%5B%5D=washington
```

but I need

```
properties?transaction_type=second&city=new_york,washington
```

How can I make this join?

UPDATE EDIT:

This method will help me but I can't find a way to implement:

```
array.map(function() { 
    return this.value; 
}).get().join(',');
```

Comment: this will  help http://stackoverflow.com/a/9966097/5571157

Comment: Is not what I need, please check my EDIT in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `[]` as they do no have any semantical meaning in this context.  Also they are duplicates and it is best practice to have unique variables.

Remove these for starts and replace with `city1` and `city2`

This is a _GET request and you will be able to access these values from the server as `city1` and `city2`.

If you want them combined into `cities`

You can write a script on the client side in JS to combine them into one key/value pair.

Comment: Cities are from database and at the end I need only city=value1,value2 . Also the input or select all are dynamic generated.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your query string in url

```
properties?transaction_type=second&city=new_york,washington

var data = 'transaction_type=' + <select_value> + '&city=' + <city_values>;
$('#filter_form').on('change', function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "properties?" + data,
        method: 'GET',
        success: function(result){
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't know the name of the input's as they are dynamically generated, so I can't build a data.