# Rest tamplate 400 null - bad request

Tags: java, spring

I have this part of code:

```
  try {
            ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, null,
                    new ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {
                    });

            if (responseEntity == null || responseEntity.getBody() == null || responseEntity.getBody() == null) {
                throw ApiException.createFrom(ResponseCode.REQUEST_INVALID, "Severity for this input is not found!");
            } else {
                return (LinkedHashMap<Object, Object>) responseEntity.getBody();

            }
```

Problem is that i always get 400 null error.

When i ask in swagger with filter parameter : `[{"attribute":"tapId","filterOperation":"EQUALS","expressionValue":"00b83d4c-afad-47fb-b66b-07c93971c69b"}]`

I get this url :

```
?filter=%5B%7B"attribute"%3A"tapId"%2C"filterOperation"%3A"EQUALS"%2C"expressionValue"%3A"00b83d4c-afad-47fb-b66b-07c93971c69b"%7D%5D
```

and this is working, but when i call it with this part of code:

```
 builder.queryParam("filter", String.join(",", filter));
```

and then

```
ResponseEntity<T> responseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(builder.build().encode().toUri(), HttpMethod.GET, null,
                        new ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {
                        });
```

i get this url

```
?filter=%7B%22attribute%22:%22tapId%22,%22filterOperation%22:%22EQUALS%22,%22expressionValue%22:%2200b83d4c-afad-47fb-b66b-07c93971c69b%22%7D
```

and this is not working and im getting this error.
Any suggestion how can i fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
%5B%7B"attribute"%3A"tapId"%2C"filterOperation"%3A"EQUALS"%2C"expressionValue"%3A"00b83d4c-afad-47fb-b66b-07c93971c69b"%7D%5D
```

This is the result of direct conversion of the filter parameter object.

```
String filterObject = "[{\"attribute\":\"tapId\",\"filterOperation\":\"EQUALS\",\"expressionValue\":\"00b83d4c-afad-47fb-b66b-07c93971c69b\"}]"
```

I think the following should work.

```
builder.queryParam("filter", filterObject);
```

Why I am thinking that?

Because `%5B = [` and so on.

You may check this.

[What does %5B and %5D in POST requests stand for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9966053/what-does-5b-and-5d-in-post-requests-stand-for)

Comment: this is working, but problem is that my filter is "dynamic" , so that i call different filters for different services, is thare any way to make this "dynamic" ?

Comment: Use a JSONArray to construct the filter. Convert it to string after that.

Comment: im not sure how to that because i have multiple "keys" ... can u give me some direction or example? im tying to find any but no success

Comment: `{"attribute":"tapId",...}` is just a map(or use json object from any library). fill your parameters using key. put that into an array list or json array and use the toString value for the filteration